# Laplace inverse of $e^{-as-bs^2}/(as+bs^2)$

Tags: exponential-function, inverse-laplace

I want to know how to do the laplace inverse transform $$e^{-as-bs^2}/(as+bs^2).$$
I have tried to use convolution and any fomula I know, but I cannot deal with one part, $e^{bs^2}$.
I searched internet and any laplace transform calculator, but I could not find any result about $e^{s^2}$.
Is it really impossible to do the Laplace transfrom of $e^{s^2}$?

Comment: Probably is Zero for: $a>0,b>0$